# I am trying to schedule a python file to run using crontab but I keep getting errors

Tags: python, cron

My code looks like this at the moment but i get the error; 'TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'crontab''

```
from crontab import CronTab
cron = CronTab()
job = cron.new(command='users/filelocation.py')
job.setall('55 10 15 11 2')
```

If anyone could help out it would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: I think you have installed wrong module *crontab*.  You should install *python-crontab*.

Comment: Try reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620394/running-a-cronjob-only-one-using-python-crontab and http://blog.appliedinformaticsinc.com/managing-cron-jobs-with-python-crontab/.